# How to query values with wildcards in PostgreSQL hstore

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to query hstore for all the values of a certain key that match a search criteria.

I can get all the values for a certain key like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
svals(slice(data, ARRAY['Supplier']))
FROM "products"
```

I can also get a specific value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
svals(slice(data, ARRAY['Supplier'])) AS sup
FROM "products"
WHERE data @> 'Supplier => Toshiba'
```

What I would really like is something like (this doesn't work):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
svals(slice(data, ARRAY['Supplier'])) AS sup
FROM "products"
WHERE data @> 'Supplier => %tosh%'
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
svals(slice(data, ARRAY['Supplier'])) AS sup
FROM "products"
WHERE lower(sup)
LIKE '%tosh%'
```

for case-insensitive search. How is this done?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can extract values by key from an `hstore` column with the [`->` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE).

```
SELECT data->'Supplier' AS sup
FROM products
WHERE lower(data->'Supplier') LIKE '%tosh%';
```

Additionally, like most expressions in PostgreSQL (excepting things like `random()`), you can index this value:

```
CREATE INDEX products_supplier_key ON products ((data->'Supplier'));
CREATE INDEX products_supplier_lowercase_key ON products ((lower(data->'Supplier')));
```

This would allow PostgreSQL to answer many such queries using the index instead of fetching each row and scanning the `hstore` column. See the notes on [Index Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html) regarding index usage with LIKE.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, willglynn!

Comment: Quick followup: is there a way to ensure that all keys are indexed like that automatically?

Comment: First answer: no. Each key needs to be in a separate index (assuming you want B-trees, which you do for that sort of matching), and adding lots of indexes is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Second answer: [sure, why not](https://gist.github.com/3759322). PostgreSQL data structures are themselves represented by data structures, and PostgreSQL lets you run procedures, so you can do anything you want. Wrapping it in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` -- or worse, folding it into a trigger -- is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: willglynn: thanks again. You saved me a bunch of time on this one. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

One caveat to willglynn's answer for anyone seeing this in the future -- the original query and the new query have slightly different behavior. Namely,

```
SELECT data->'Supplier' AS sup
FROM products;
```

will include a NULL value assuming at least one row doesn't have an assignment for Supplier.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
svals(slice(data, ARRAY['Supplier']))
FROM "products"
```

will not return the NULL value.